# SQL query to group time series measurements into single record?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a table in a MySQL database containing measurements from multiple sensors in roughly 30s intervals, each with a timestamp, like this:

```
<timestamp, source_device, measurement>
<2016-04-01 01:00:00.1234, sensor 1, 1.234>
<2016-04-01 01:00:01.5467, sensor 2, 2.543>
<2016-04-01 01:00:00.8376, sensor 3, 1.318>
<2016-04-01 01:00:31.7365, sensor 2, 1.927>
<2016-04-01 01:00:30.2610, sensor 1, 2.701>
<2016-04-01 01:00:30.9576, sensor 3, 1.853>
```

Note that the first 3 records are at *roughly* the same time, although the timestamps do not match exactly. I need to export summary CSVs and display the data on a frontend console. For example, a client might request all data for a certain time period from sensors 2 and 3, in five minute intervals, in a downloadable CSV. I would like to execute this as a single query with a common (rounded) timestamp:

```
<timestamp, sensor_2_measurement, sensor_3_measurement>
<2016-04-01 01:00, 2.543, 1.318>
<2016-04-01 01:05, 3.015, 1.692>
<2016-04-01 01:10, 2.752, 1.494>
```

At the moment, I am doing separate queries for each sensor, but this requires me to load the full query results into memory before constructing a CSV and puts some strain on my application stitching together the CSV rows. Is there a way to boil this down to a single query? Bonus points for a sqlalchemy implementation, but I can work with a pure SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gets the average value for each time unit rounded to 5 minute intervals:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(24*60/5))*(24*60/5)) as ts,
       avg(case when source_device = 1 then measurement end) as sensor_1,
       avg(case when source_device = 2 then measurement end) as sensor_2,
       avg(case when source_device = 3 then measurement end) as sensor_3
from t
group by ts;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay accepting the answer, but this is almost exactly what I was looking for. Questions:
1) Which timestamps is it actually using? I see that the timestamps are roughly 5 min apart, but they aren't on any round number, and if I request only recent devices, I get many early results where all measurement columns are NULL. Which source_device timestamp is it using?

Comment: If the measurement values are `NULL`, then there are no rows with that measurement during that period.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar problem, I ended up slightly modifying @Gordon Linoff's excellent answer to group the measurements into round timestamps (the query in the accepted answer will give buckets that are 5 min apart, but not at rounded times like 1:00:00, 1:05:00, etc.). I used:

```
select timestamp,
   avg(case when source_device = 1 then measurement end) as sensor_1,
   avg(case when source_device = 2 then measurement end) as sensor_2,
   avg(case when source_device = 3 then measurement end) as sensor_3
from t
group by unix_timestamp(timestamp) div 300;
```

Hope this helps someone else.